# Accessing ThreadLocal values from a method which a thread has invoked?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I have used `ThreadLocal` very little, however I need to know about it for work reasons. I did search on this, and came to know about the concept.

I made sample example below:

**ThreadLocalMain.java** -> Main driver program

```
package com.example.threads.threadlocal;

public class ThreadLocalMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1("First");
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1("Second");
        Thread1 t3 = new Thread1("Third");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

**Thread1.java**  -> Which uses `ThreadLocal`

```
package com.example.threads.threadlocal;

import com.example.threads.threadlocal.utils.Util1;

public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private static Integer unique_id = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static ThreadLocal tl = new ThreadLocal() {

        @Override
        public Integer initialValue() {
            return (++unique_id);
        }
    };

    public Thread1(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Current thread is --> " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with thread local value as --> " + tl.get());

        Util1 u1 = new Util1();
        u1.display(tl);
    }
```

**Util.java** --> In this I want to check Thread's ThreadLocal value

```
package com.example.threads.threadlocal.utils;

public class Util1 {
    public void display(ThreadLocal tl) {
        System.out.println("Inside Util1#display() method, executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " my thread local value is -->  " + tl.get());
    }
}
```

I have main driver program, which creates 3-thread, and in thread class there is `ThreadLocal` which saves values for current thread.

My question is how can we print the value of ThreadLocal for current thread which has invoked a method on some object. In this case the object is `Util`. I was able to do by passing the instance of `ThreadLocal` into `Util's` `display()` method.

**So my question:**

Is it possible to print the value of ThreadLocal in a method without passing `ThreadLocal` reference to the method? Is it feasible at all? Is my method not the way it is intended to use `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: you saved the value of `Threadlocal` into a static variable `Thread1.t1`. This variable is accessible from anywhere, no need to pass reference.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: If i create it like a "normal" variable , don't Thread have any means to access irrespective which code the thread is executing? I need hook for that in order to retrieve the value?

Comment: just find a code example and strictly follow it. Do not invent your own bike. Only if you cannot reproduce a published example, ask question here.

Comment: actually, the value of `Thread1.t1` is that hook. When yo access it with `get` and `set`, it takes into account the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you do not execute code in different threads in *display* method, you can pass value of thread local instead the thread local to *display* method. Following code will lead the same result

```
@Override
public void run() {
      System.out.println("Current thread is --> " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " with thread local value as --> " + tl.get());

    Util u1 = new Util();
    u1.display(tl.get());
}

public class Util {
  public void display(Object value) {
    System.out.println("Inside Util1#display() method, executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + " my thread local value is -->  " + value);
}
```

}